# not all arguments converted during string formatting ".error"

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code show not all arguments converted during string formatting error can anyone solve this

```py
with open('../jangi/Downloads/easyocr-demo-master/save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in results:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the value of `results`? It looks like `item` is not a string.

Comment: We can't solve this without knowing what you're trying to accomplish. You need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code (since `results` is not defined) and expected output. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
f.write(f"{item}\n")
```

or

```
f.write("%s\n" % str(item))
```

It will write `item` as a string regardless what type it is

Comment: This might work, but it might also not be what OP's going for. The question's unclear. I just wanted to mention that in case anyone else ends up here with a similar problem.